# TypeScript conditional types with classes that are structurally equivalent

Tags: typescript

I have something like the following:

```js
declare class Base {
  constructor(a: string)
}

declare class A extends Base {
  constructor(a: number)
}

declare class B extends Base {
  constructor(a: object)
}

declare class C extends Base {
  constructor(a: boolean)
}

type ResponseMapper<T extends Base> = T extends A 
  ? number 
  : T extends B 
  ? object 
  : T extends C 
  ? boolean 
  : never;

declare function getValue<T extends Base>(input: T): ResponseMapper<T>

let x: number = getValue(new A(1))
let y: object = getValue(new B({}))
let z: boolean = getValue(new C(true))
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwEIoQbwFD0QHsA7ZAFxgFcwzCYAKKALnnJgEtiBzASlwF9cuUEjiJoqeAEF4IAB5kQxYGkzIc%20IqQrVaDZvGKUAtgCMQMPoOHhoYpJPSyFSlRizw8BMCTa66jCyEpgBW4GRWQiJ2CA5oAMLOisqqHl5afjQBBqaEhBAgUMSRuGQAngAOCABKIMgVviAAslAVVTAAPAAqSa6p6gB88AC88D3yyW4ymgD8hibmMPCaLOMuKRjLBHPBYTRb8Ku9G4mz8Ln5hcQHLMQgAG4WANxRtrAIAGaUxDTsJPBcEBkABqUAglBA3WObjUIAG9E4FUoZFWPBYtXqjRabQs3QGQgKZHgcluCwsIwBQNB4JA9DuAHdpPQAIw8PiE%20BlIKhcIUwEgsEQukgRnoejYfhs3AcgBeLAuBSKfKpgtpDPg8XoOhAbKAA)

This doesn't quite work because A, B, and C are all structurally equivalent. So in `ResponseMapper`, if I pass an instance of `B` or `C` in, it still evaluates to `number`. So the variable declarations for `y` and `z` end up being type errors.

I figured out a workaround is to add a fake property to each class that makes the types no longer be structurally equivalent. So this works:

```js
declare class Base {
  constructor(a: string)
}

declare class A extends Base {
  _name?: "A"
  constructor(a: number)
}

declare class B extends Base {
  _name?: "B"
  constructor(a: object)
}

declare class C extends Base {
  _name?: "C"
  constructor(a: boolean)
}

type ResponseMapper<T extends Base> = T extends A 
  ? number 
  : T extends B 
  ? object 
  : T extends C 
  ? boolean 
  : never;

declare function getValue<T extends Base>(input: T): ResponseMapper<T>

let x: number = getValue(new A(1))
let y: object = getValue(new B({}))
let z: boolean = getValue(new C(true))
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwEIoQbwFD0QHsA7ZAFxgFcwzCYAKKALnnJgEtiBzASlwF9cuUEjiJoqeAEF4IAB5kQxYGkzIc%20eAH1iUALYgA-CwBEUk5rAk21Wg2bxilPQCMQMPoOHhoYpJPRZBSUVDCx4PAIdfSNTdAsCK1IKWzpGFkIXACtwMk8hEV8EfzQAYSDFZVVwyO1dA2N4E1KEomSqGjSHF0JCCBAoYnzcMgBPAAcEACUQZHHrEABZKHHJmAAeABUKkOr1AD54AF54bflK0JlNQ0dnNxh4TRYz4KqMR4IbzJyaD-hnnZvcrXeA9PoDYh-FjEEAAN3cAG4Cj5YAgAGaUYg0dgkeBcEBkABqUAglBAW0BoTUIH29E440oZGePBYMzmC2Wq3cW32Qn6ZHgcmhd3cxzxBOJpJA9BhAHdpPQAIw8Pj8%20CjDLZXJi-FEklkmUgeXoejYfgq3BqgBeLDB-UGOol%20ulcvgpXoKRAKqAA)

Is there a better way to get this to work that doesn't require adding a fake field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try using this type:

```
type ResponseMapper<T, U> = T extends new (a: infer R) => U ? R : never;

declare function getValue<T extends new (a: V) => U, U, V = ResponseMapper<T, U>>(input: U): V;
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwEIoQbwFD0QHsA7ZAFxgFcwzCYAKKALnnJgEtiBzASlwF9cuUEjiJoqeAEF4IAB5kQxYGkzIc+IqQrVaDZvGKUAtgCMQMPoOHhoYpJPSyFSlRizw8BMCTa66jCyEpgBW4GRWQiJ2CA5oAMLOisqqHl5afjQBBqaEhBAgUMSRuGQAngAOCABKIMgVviAAslAVVTAAPAAqADTwAKoAfPAAvPBdSa5oxCAA7vCB8JwAZhbw1Tyjw-3wAPzr8CwzAG4WANxRtrAIy5TENOwk8FwgZABqUBCUIN2TKYZzBYGN6bEbbPr9PpvUbrOoNUjNVrtboQwaDeicCqUMgsfo8FhvC64ApkeByI4mcwwGEvd6fb70GbzKT0ACMPD4JPgZSCoXCNNeHy+IEZgPQ9Gw-A5xNe8AAXixcvlCsQBXThaL5vF6DoQBygA)